# Unzipping files downloaded from the Arxiv server

Tags: tar, gzip, winrar

I want to download the source Tex files (not the pdf) of this document:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0322

After downloading [here](http://arxiv.org/format/1306.0322v3), I get a weird file with the ".0322v3" (the second part of the doc code) extension. I've tried renaming the file using a .tar.gz or .gz extension, which I haven't been able to decompress with Winrar. "There was an error at the end of file".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a .tar.gz file in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/215629/how-to-open-a-tar-gz-file-in-windows)

Comment: I was having the same trouble, until I noticed that the file I was trying to open was a plain .tex (without the extension).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this  [page](http://archivo.online-convert.com/es/convertir-a-zip)
to convert the tar.gz file into a zip file. It will output a file that you can open in windows.. even if you have that extension problem.

I had the same problem an i could open the .tex inside with this workaround.

Comment: The trap here is that the received file isn't compressed, it"s a plain TAR archive. 7zip explodes it without fuss.