# "Opens with" missing from properties of a .tar.gz file?

Tags: windows-explorer

[image: Reference image here]

I'm trying to open a `.tar.gz` file. Why doesn't the property screen have the "Opens with:" section and instead just has "Description:" ?

Comment: Because you don't have any software installed that can deal with *.tar.gz?

Comment: Uhh, yes I do. I have WinRAR.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a .tar.gz file in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/215629/how-to-open-a-tar-gz-file-in-windows)

Comment: You can set the associated program by right-clicking on the file in Explorer, choosing **Open with** (depending on your Windows version, you may need Ctrl-right-click), then click **Try an App on this PC**; choose the App from the list and tick **Always use this app ...**. Alternatively, set the file type as one that WinRAR will handle in its options.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has a different API than previous windows for file associations.  Sometimes programs can't automatically set defaults.

So you may need to do what @AFH mentioned in the comments.  If it doesn't work, try right clicking WinRAR and selecting "Run As Administrator", and make sure you are using the latest WinRAR.

If you can't get it with WinRAR, 7-zip is a good alternative.

> You can set the associated program by right-clicking on the file in
>   Explorer, choosing Open with (depending on your Windows version, you
>   may need Ctrl-right-click), then click Try an App on this PC; choose
>   the App from the list and tick Always use this app .... Alternatively,
>   set the file type as one that WinRAR will handle in its options.